# How do I properly reshape nested arrays (both 1D) arrays into a 2D array for fitting to my Keras model?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have changed my data pipelines for a project I'm working on, and it has caused a minor issue. One of the inputs to my model (before batching) needs to be of the shape (num_examples, num_features). But currently, it is a nested array, which looks like the following:

```
data = array([array([ 1172, 41031,   348, ...,     0,     0,     0]),
              array([34145, 19247, 11507, ...,     0,     0,     0]),
              array([ 9223,  2188, 21658, ...,     0,     0,     0]),
              ...
             ]
```

When I call data.shape, it returns (915,). And when I call data[0].shape, it returns (11481,). But I need to transform this into just one array with the shape (915, 11481).

I have tried using the np.reshape function, however I can't get it to work. Can someone please suggest how I can reshape these nested arrays into one array of the proper shape? Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I have done it in a sort-of hacky way by creating a blank list, appending each array to the list, and then calling np.asarray on the list and this has worked, however, if anyone has a more elegant solution it would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code for my current solution:

```
def reshape_sequences(sequences):
    temp = []
    for sequence in sequences:
        temp.append(sequence)
    return np.asarray(temp)
```

Comment: Check the shape of all 915 nest arrays.  I suspect one or more has a different shape.  If they really are the same then `np.stack(data)` should produce the desired 2d.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed! And yeah, they are all of the same shape since I had made all of them beforehand with the pad_sequences function from Keras. @hpaulj